# typesetting equations for epub book

Tags: creation, epub

I would like to write an ebook (epub format) which is math and chemistry heavy. 
So far I found a way to typeset my equations, produce images and insert that to the text, but it needs a lot of handwork and have problem tracking all the images. Also, it gets very big pretty soon. So I am looking for ways to do it more intelligently/with less errors.

If there any other way to typeset equations and embed them into the text? Is there any way to display LaTex or similarly typeset equations?